# Delphi TListview - search for item and auto-scroll to that item

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

Delphi 10.4.1 with FireMonkey.

I have 50 items on a `TListView`, with IDs from 1 to 50.  No code posted here because I don't even know where to get started.

If I did a search for ID=35, is there a way to make
`TListView` move exactly to the position of that item programmatically
so that the item is in full view?

Comment: Yes. There is a way to do that. If you are stuck at a specific problem while trying to do it. Include the Code you got so far. Otherwise this question is way too broad to answer.

Comment: VCL's `TListItem` has a `MakeVisible()` method for this exact purpose. A shame FireMonkey's `TListViewItem` doesn't have a similar method.

Comment: @Ancaron apologies, but I used a TDataset.Locate as it's livebinding but it didn't move at all (not even to a wrong position) so I didn't include it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah, thanks for the pointer.. will be useful for future windows apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is trivial:

```
ListView.ScrollTo(Item.Index);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! tested, this works! upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In short: Set the `SelectedItem` and the list view scrolls to this element in the list.

In long: You can iterate through the list and select the item that matches your search criteria:

```
for var c := 0 to ListView1.ItemCount - 1 do
  if ListView1.Items[c].Text = <TextToSearch> then
  begin
    ListView1.Selected := ListView1.Items[c]; 
    break;
  end;
```

Unfortunately, you do not explain how to save the ID in the list item. My example assumes that this is done in the list text. Alternatively you can also use e.g. `Tag` or `TagString`.

Comment: Apologies for the info that was missing. I'm storing the ID in a `TListItemText` called TextID object as it's a DynamicAppearance listview.  how do I iterate through each row of TextID ?

Comment: you may also wish to change SelectedItem to Selected for Firemonkey.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! tested, this works! upvoted the answer.

Comment: Correct, I have changed to Selected.